# Specify return type using useFetch of vueuse library

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vueuse

I'm trying to specify the return type of my data using the [useFetch()](https://vueuse.org/core/useFetch/) function of the [vueuse](https://vueuse.org/) library (**not** the [one of Nuxt3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/examples/composables/use-fetch/)!)

The code below is working to get the data from the API but the return type of the data (person) is not inferred correctly.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useFetch } from '@vueuse/core'

interface Person {
  id: number
  first_name: string
  last_name: string
}

const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/persons/1/'

const { isFetching, data: person } = useFetch<Person>(url).get().json()

console.log(person)
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="isFetching">
      <LoadingIndicator />
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <div v-if="person">
          {{ person.id }}: {{ person.first_name }} {{ person.last_name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

As you can see below, the type of data remains of type `Any`. (I'm hovering the data value):
[image]
The console log:
[image]

If I skip the call to `json()`, then the type is inferred correctly and I have code completion in the template. However, the object is no longer parsed as json...
[image]
The console log:
[image]
Any idea how to get the type inferred correctly ? or is this just a problem of my IDE?

Comment: Can you console log the `person` object? It is easier for  us to debug if you can reproduce your problem on an online tool like stackblitz

Comment: @Duannx I have edited my question adding the console log

Comment: You should use like this `get().json<Person>()` because the `json()` function will convert result to JSON and returns default type `any`